# how to check if process is running or not every 10mins for one hour using shell

Tags: shell

e.g. my process name is test. If I use below 
ps -ef | grep test 
I see that process is running. Now I want to check this every 10mins for one hour and print success if it's running successfully for one hour. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: This might be a question for ServerFault or Linux/Unix, but I think you'll need to be more specific if you choose to post to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Put your command into a shell script, and if the process is running when the shell script is ran print "success". Add it as a cron job that runs every 10 minutes:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/scriptorcommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason to just check at the end of an hour?

```
sleep 3600

# Check if process is running
```

Answer (score 0):

```
always_alive=1; 
for i in `seq 1 6`; do 
  if [ -n "`pgrep test`" ]; then 
    echo 'RUNNING'; 
  else 
    echo 'BOO'; 
    always_alive=0; 
  fi; 
  sleep 600; # 10 minutes 
done; 

if [ "$always_alive" == "1" ]; then 
  echo 'ALWAYS RUNNING'; 
else 
  echo 'NOT ALWAYS RUNNING'; 
fi
```